# How to determine direction between 2 coordinates?

Tags: iphone, ios, coordinates

Hello everyone i was wondering how to rotate an arrow i.e uiimageview according to 2 coordinates. I already have coordinate A latitude & longitude and also coordinate B latitude & longitude. I dot want to use location manager start updating header since I already have my start & end coordinates. Thank you :)

Comment: Have you googled it? Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809337/calculating-bearing-between-two-cllocationcoordinate2ds

Comment: Check my answer on --

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730770/with-what-coordinates-do-i-use-to-manually-draw-a-custom-path-with-an-mkmapview/16731483#16731483

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the direction in radiants

```
radiants = arctan((latB-latA)/(lonB-LonA))
```

You can convert it to degrees with

```
degrees = (radiants*180)/π
```